# How do I get the transient fields from EclipseLink's `SingularAttributeImpl`?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, transient

How do I get the fields annotated with `@Transient` from EclipseLink's `SingularAttributeImpl`?  I realize I could use reflection to get all the fields for the class and then check for the `@Transient` annotation.  I was hoping for an easier solution like `SingularAttributeImpl.isTransient()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Metamodel as per section 5.1 "Metamodel API Interfaces" of the JPA spec, is for

> accessing the meta- model of the persistent state and relationships of
> the managed classes of a persistence unit.

If it is transient it will not be registered in the JPA Metamodel.